# How to split Spark dataframe rows into columns?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Pyspark dataframe and I would like to split its rows into columns based on unique values of a given column, joining with values of the other column. For illustrative purposes, let me use the following example, where my original dataframe is `df`.

```py
df.show()
+-----+-----+
| col1| col2|
+-----+-----+
|   z1|   a1|
|   z1|   b2|
|   z1|   c3|
|   x1|   a1|
|   x1|   b2|
|   x1|   c3|
+-----+-----+
```

What I would like to do is to split on the **unique** values of `col1`, thus generating a new column (say, `col3`) by joining on the values of `col2`. The resulting dataframe that I am after would look like the following:

```py
+-----+-----+-----+
| col1| col2| col3|
+-----+-----+-----+
|   z1|   a1|  x1 |
|   z1|   b2|  x1 |
|   z1|   c3|  x1 |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

This illustrative example only contains two unique values in `col1` (i.e. `z1` and `x1`). Ideally, I would like to write a piece of code which automatically detects unique values in `col1` and therefore generates a new corresponding column. Does anyone know where can I start from?

**Edit**: It is arbitrary that `z1` and `x1` end up being in `col1` and `col3`, respectively. It could definitely be the other way round since I am simply just interested in splitting by unique values.

Many thanks in advance,

Marioanzas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're trying to group by `col2` and collect a set of distinct `col1` values.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.groupBy('col2').agg(F.collect_set('col1').alias('col'))
df3 = df2.select(
    'col2',
    *[F.col('col')[i] for i in range(df2.select(F.max(F.size('col'))).head()[0])]
)

df3.show()
+----+------+------+
|col2|col[0]|col[1]|
+----+------+------+
|  b2|    z1|    x1|
|  a1|    z1|    x1|
|  c3|    z1|    x1|
+----+------+------+
```

Then you can rearrange/rename the columns as you wish.

It's not obvious to me why `z1` should go in `col1` and `x1` in `col3` in your question. It could very well be the other way round - there is no way to tell from your logic.

Comment: Hi @mck , many thanks for your suggestion! I will try it shortly. Regarding the last part of your answer, it is arbitrary that `z1` and `x1` go in `col1` and `col3`, respectively. As you mention, it could definitely be the other way round! I will update the wording of the question in order to make this clearer. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can `join` using two conditions and `dropDuplicates`:

```
df.alias('left').join(
    df.alias('right'),
    on = [
          F.col('left.col2') == F.col('right.col2'),
          F.col('left.col1') != F.col('right.col1')
          ]
).dropDuplicates(['col2']).show()
```

Output:

```
+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col1|col2|
+----+----+----+----+
|  x1|  b2|  z1|  b2|
|  x1|  a1|  z1|  a1|
|  x1|  c3|  z1|  c3|
+----+----+----+----+
```

Then you can `drop` and rename columns:

```
df.alias('left').join(
    df.alias('right'),
    on = [
          F.col('left.col2') == F.col('right.col2'),
          F.col('left.col1') != F.col('right.col1')
          ]
).dropDuplicates(['col2'])\
.drop(F.col('right.col2'))\
.select(
    F.col('right.col1'), F.col('col2'), F.col('left.col1').alias('col3')
).show()
```

Output:

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|  z1|  b2|  x1|
|  z1|  a1|  x1|
|  z1|  c3|  x1|
+----+----+----+
```

You can also use SQL:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView('df')

spark.sql(
    """
    SELECT
      l.col1 AS col1,
      l.col2 AS col2,
      r.col1 AS col3 
    FROM df AS l
    INNER JOIN df AS r
    ON l.col2 = r.col2
    AND l.col1 <> r.col1
    """
).dropDuplicates(['col2']).show()
```

Output:

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|  z1|  b2|  x1|
|  z1|  a1|  x1|
|  z1|  c3|  x1|
+----+----+----+
```